# zsh name in terminal changed to a number when logged in

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I used to see myname@my-Macbook... when I open my Terminal, but recently it changed to myname@192. Why did this happen, and is there a way to change it back? Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell us, how  `PS1` is defined..

Answer (score 0):

Check out what `hostname` returns. If it returns that number, search for changing the hostname. If not, your shell prompt has gotten messed up, and an easy way to fix it is to trash your shell config (`.zshenv`, `.zshrc`, etc).